# Change image used in CSS based on ui culture. asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, localization

How can i use different image based on uiculture in my asp.net webpage. I am able to change strings via resource file. but how can i change images.  Below is the example of how my code is., ie, I have one A tag and a class assigned to it, the class is defined in CSS. And a background image is used in the class. Now how can i make my website pick a different image based on culture. Can any one help in this regard..

```
In default.aspx file
<a class="classproperties">

In mystylesheet.css file
 .classproperties { 
      background-image: url(../img/myimg.png);    
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "based on culture"?

Comment: yes,. for en-US  i use a image and need to load different image for another culture example fr-FR

Answer (score 0):

Add image paths in Resource files, then you can use it like

```
<div style="background-image: url('@Resources.ImagePath')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using and extending the resource files is a viable option. Another option would be to have secondary culture-based CSS files added in programmatically.

With search engines getting smarter, you could use javascript to add culture based class information to elements that are going to be changed, and then cascade the stylesheet

```
 .classproperties { background-image: url(../img/generic.png); }
 .classproperties .enUS { background-image: url(../img/enUS.png); }
 .classproperties .frFR { background-image: url(../img/frFR.png); }
 .classproperties .frCA { background-image: url(../img/frCA.png); }
```

the beauty with this method is that jQuery and other frameworks can leverage the HTML5 data attributes on elements so that you could just loop through all elements with a specific value and append the additional class information to them